# How to update rendered element using ejs

Tags: javascript, ejs

I am using EJS for template rendering and have below line of code:

```
var html = new EJS({
    url : 'http://' + host + ':1010/OtherDomain/article-popup.ejs'
}).render({
    price : '$20'
});
```

Template:

```
 <span><%= price %></span>
```

now I want to update content of the `price` element.

I read the doc from here https://code.google.com/p/embeddedjavascript/wiki/Templates
but not getting how to update value of element using EJS.

Please guide.
Any fiddle will be great

Comment: Where is your template?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl please see the template part I added.

Comment: Just render it over and over with different values and update it. EJS doesn't do 2 way bindings or anything like that.

Comment: This is probably more helpful than that wiki page: http://www.embeddedjs.com/getting_started.html

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl in this line 
new EJS({url: 'comments.ejs'}).update('element_id', '/comments.json')
What does 'element_id' referes to ?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum mine value for element is coming from ajax response dynamically

Comment: It refers to the element ID of the DOM element you want to update.

Answer (score 0):

Use the update method.

Your Code:

```
var html = new EJS
({
    url : 'http://' + host + ':1010/OtherDomain/article-popup.ejs'
}).render({price : '$20'});
```

To update use:

```
var update = new EJS
({
    url : 'http://' + host + ':1010/OtherDomain/article-popup.ejs'
}).update(html, { price: '$30'})
```